# Use a variable in a nested JSON.parse API call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering if there is a way in Google script to use a variable to get data and write it on a cell from a nested API call.
For example:

```
var symbol = "BTC";

  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+apikey+"&symbol="+symbol+"&convert=EUR");

  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  index.getRange(2,1).setValue([parcedData.data.BTC.symbol]);
  index.getRange(2,2).setValue([parcedData.data.BTC.quote.EUR.price]);
```

This is the code I use to retrieve BTC price from new Coinmarketcap API (documentation is here https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest). Since I already declare the BTC symbol in a variable, is there a way to substitute BTC in "setValue"? Something like:

```
index.getRange(2,1).setValue([parcedData.data.+symbol+.symbol]);
                                 variable here ^^^^^^
```

This is not working of course, is there a way to make it works?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, nothing stops you from accessing a variable property name here, just remember to use bracket notation - `parcedData.data[symbol].symbol` - so long as the `symbol` variable is reachable within the scope of `setValue()`, you should be good to go.

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, since ES6 came around, you can even use calculated properties (for example, `parcedData.data[ doSomething() ]`, as long as `doSomething` returns a property name